# GET POST mysql data on next page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok, I haven't done much of this sort of stuff, so I am clueless right now.

On the first page you hit the form submit that generates a bunch of information/stuff and displays it underneath submit button, but I don't know how to take the displayed information and use it on the next page I will show some of my code. btw I know the code is bad, just ignore that fact.

```
<form name="input" action="slaymonster.php" method="post" id="id">
  <div align="center">
    <input name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Explore Map!"/>
  </div>
</form> 

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

include 'includes/mapstuff.php';


// So here we pick a random row from the table pokemon notice the order by rand
$sql23 = "SELECT * FROM map1pokemon ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";
// We then check for errors
$result23 = mysql_query($sql23) or die(mysql_error());
// we then make the result into a virable called battle_get23
$battle_get23 = mysql_fetch_array($result23);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$battle_get23['pokemon']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

// Now we need to make sure the image is safe be for we use it
$pic2= mysql_real_escape_string($battle_get2['pic']);
$pic = strip_tags($pic2);


include 'includes/maptypes.php';


?>


<form name="inputt" action="" method="post">
  <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" class="catch" value="Catch Pokemon" name="catch">
  </div>
</form>

<p></p>

<?php
echo "You have just found a " ;
echo $randomview97[0];
echo " ";

echo $battle_get23['pokemon'];


$_SESSION['pokemon'] = $battle_get23['pokemon']; 
$_SESSION['type'] = $randomview97[0];
$_SESSION['pic'] = $battle_get2;
$_SESSION['money'] = $randomview2[0];
$_SESSION['level'] = $randomview3[0];
$_SESSION['ticket'] = $randomview4;

?>
<p></p>
<?php
echo "You have gained ".$randomview3[0]." levels" ;
echo " ";
?>
<p></p>
<?php
echo "You have received $".$randomview2[0]."" ;
echo " ";
?>
<p></p>
<?php
echo "</center>";
}

?>
```

it displays the pokemon's picture it's name, type,amount of money you got ect...

I need all that information to be useable on the next page.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your PHP code, be sure to include session_start(); 
You are already using session variables, so you should refer here to see what a PHP session is: [PHP session_start() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). It makes sure to do exactly what you are asking for (someone may point out that in certain cases session_start(); is not necessary, but for your purposes, while learning, stick to the Manual for best practices)

This information will be usable on the next 'page', just as the manual describes, and will be available, until you call something like session_destroy().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the information from one page to another. You have to put the result inside the form tag. Then it is possible to pass the information to another page. Or you can put it on the session and get information from any page.

you got my point? If you explain what you want to do. Then I will do something for you.